# How to add external jars to build.gradle from local system folder

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have created a custom plugin in groovy. now i want to add it to my `build.gradle` in another project:

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Above lines does not seem to work for me. i have put my external jar in libs folder in project root folder. I am getting error plugin with id not found.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Have you added it to the buildscript dependendencies closure? Or just to the project dependencies?

Comment: just project dependencies.

Comment: if you add a plugin, you have to declare it as buildscript dependency oike this: `buildscript{dependencies { compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') }}`

Comment: apply plugin: 'java'
buildscript{
 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
 }
}
repositories { jcenter() }
dependencies {
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
 compile localGroovy()
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin:'ExternalJar'

task runScript(type: JavaExec) {
 description 'Run Groovy script'
 main = 'com.plugin.HelloWorld'
 classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
 if (project.hasProperty('custom')) {
  args project.getProperty('custom')
 }
}

defaultTasks 'runScript'

Comment: this is my build.gradle, After giving buildscript i am getting new error now "A problem occurred evaluating root project 'CustPlugin'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of
type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
."

Comment: Am i missing any more important thing?

Comment: Oh, yes, you cannot use `compile` in buildscript, change it to `classpath`. I just didnt note it in my previews answer

Comment: classpath fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') is it now correct?

Comment: seems so, if it's still within `buildscript` closure and path is correct your plugin should be found

Comment: "A problem occurred evaluating root project 'CustPlugin'.
> Plugin with id 'ExternalJar' not found." stuck with this error